# Incompatibilidade de versão 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App'

Tags: asp.net-core

Boa tarde, estou começando os estudos com .NET Core para um projeto e tive que trocar de computador, ao restaurar o projeto estou tendo o seguinte problema:

It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.2.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      3.0.0 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

Sei que para resolver ou atualizo a aplicação ou faço downgrade do que foi instalado, como estou estudando, acho interessante ver os dois cenários, então pergunto, como posso fazer o upgrade dos arquivos ou o dowgrade do que está instalado. Estou usando Visual Studio Code para trabalhar.

Comment: O .net core pode rodar diferentes versões lado a lado. Então você pode instalar o .net core 2.2 e manter o 3.0 sem maiores problemas. Para não ter que atualizar a aplicação você pode instalar a versão 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O .NET Core framework permite que seja instalado e executado diferentes versões na mesma máquina. Isso é conhecido como "instalações lado a lado".

Para saber todas versões instaladas na sua máquina você pode usar o seguinte comando no seu prompt de comando:

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

E para saber qual versão esta em uso:

```
dotnet --version
```

Você pode baixar qualquer versão do SDK do .NET Core em sua [página oficial](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core)